# Videos, songs, and all media playing in fast forward

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, music, multimedia, hp-pavilion

Whenever I try to play a video or song, on YouTube or using Banshee, the media plays as if it's in fast forward. Everything ran fine, videos and songs played normal, all hardware worked fine, and then suddenly tonight it started doing this fast forward thing. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on my HP Pavillion Dv7-4285dx, no modifications to my hardware or software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if your speakers are working. You can test this from System Settings / Sound / Hardware tab.

I had the same problem this morning. The reason this happened for me - I changed the device for sound output from analog to HDMI while fiddling with the sound settings last night. You can check the device you are using from System Settings / Sound / Output tab.

Comment: Yes I forgot to follow up on this a while ago. I had to switch from ATI Manhattan HDMI to Internal Analog. All media, including Flash videos and mp3 files, now play normally. Thanks Preetam!

Comment: This answer would be wondrously helpful, excepting the fact that there IS NO "hardware tab". Using Ubuntu 12.04, and I see "Output", "Input", Sound Effects", and "Applications". Is there somewhere else we can find the settings for Sound hardware? Or is it this: On the main dialogue screen for sound settings, I have options for "LFE on Separate Mono Output/ No Amplifier *Built-in Audio*" and "LFE on Separate Mono Output/ Amplifier *Built-in Audio*" It seems to make no difference which of these is selected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Go to System Settings / Sound / Hardware tab. In the Hardware tab, select your HDMI device and in the 'Profile' combo box below, select off. It should default back to your Internal Audio device instantly at this point. Problem solved.